# .net collections memory optimization - will this method work?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, collections

Just like almost any other big `.NET` application, my current `C#` project contains many `.net` collections .
Sometimes I don't know, from the beginning, what the size of a Collection (List/ObservableCollection/Dictionary/etc.) is going to be.
But there are many times when I do know what it is going to be.

I often get an `OutOfMemoryException` and I've been told it can happen not only because process size limits, but also because of fragmentation.

So my question is this - will setting collection's size (using the capacity argument in the constructor) every time I know its expected size help me prevent at least some of the fragmentation problems ?

This quote is from the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z(v=VS.80).aspx) :

> If the size of the collection can be
>   estimated, specifying the initial
>   capacity eliminates the need to
>   perform a number of resizing
>   operations while adding elements to
>   the List.

But still, I don't want to start changing big parts of my code for something that might not be the real problem.

Has it ever helped any of you to solve out of memory problems ?

Comment: Have you used a memory profiler to find the culprit(s)?

Comment: Will a memory profiling help me discover collections resizing occurences?

Comment: It'll help you find the largest and most significant collections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying an initial size will rarely if ever get rid of an OutOfMemory issue - unless your collection size is millions of object in which case you should really not keep such a collection.

Resizing a collection involves defining a completely new array with a new additional size and then copying the memory. If you are already close to out of memory, yes, this can cause an out of memory since the new array cannot be allocated.

**However, 99 out of 100, you have a memory leak in your app and collection resizing issues is only a symptom of it.**

Comment: I chose you answer of the others (who were great as well) because of your last sentence, which was the most helpful and important to remember.. thanks

Comment: Thanks, that's my gut feeling. If you put another question on the specific case of your app, I could probably help more.

Comment: @programmer indeed, @Aliostad makes a very valid point. For reference, **95%** of the times I've had a (perceived) memory leak, it has turned out to be an event that I didn't unsubscribe, that is causing objects to be kept in the graph.

Comment: If microsoft divided the OutOfMemoryException into a set of more specific memory-related exceptions - that would have been great..

Answer (score 3):

If you are hitting OOM, then you may be being overly aggressive with the data, but to answer the question:

Yes, this may help *some* - as if it has to keep growing the collections by doubling, it could end up allocating and copying twice as much memory *for the underlying array* (or more precicely, for the earlier smaller copies that are discarded). Most of these intermediate arrays will be collected promptly, but when they get big you are using the "large object heap", which is harder to compact.

Starting with the correct size prevents all the intermediate copies of the array.

However, it also depends what is **in** the array matters. Typically, for classes, there is more data **in each object** (plus overheads for references etc) - meaning the list is not necessarily the biggest culprit for memory use; you might be burning up most of the memory on objects.

Note that x64 will allow more *overall* space, but arrays are limited to 2GB - and if each reference doubles in size this halves the maximum effective length of the array.

Personally I would look at breaking the huge sets into smaller *chains* of lists; jagged lists, for example.

Comment: regarding jagged lists - that would be, in my opinion, too much of a hassle to change my code and design just for having some collections optimizations .

Comment: @Marc-Gravell - just to be clear...it's not that the LOH is "harder to compact" as you note - the LOH is NOT compacted (at least as of .NET 4.7)

Answer (score 2):

.NET has a compating garbage collector, so you probably won't run into fragmentation problems on the normal .NET heap. You can however get memory fragmentation if you're using lots of unmanaged memory (e.g. through GDI+, COM, etc.). Also, the large object heap isn't compacted, so that can get fragmented, too. IIRC an object is put into the LOH if it's bigger than 80kb. So if you have many collections that contain more than 20k objects, you *might* get fragmentation problems.

But instead of guessing where the problem might be, it might be better to narrow the problem down some more: When do you get the OutOfMemoryExceptions? How much memory is the application using at that time? Using a tool like WinDbg or memory profilers you should be able to find out how much of that memory is on the LOH.

That said, it's always a good idea to set the capacity of List and other data structures in advance if you know it. Otherwise, the List will double it's capacity everytime you add an item and hit the capacity limit which means lots of unnecessary allocation and copy operations.

Comment: one of (but not the only) criteria for the LOH is that the item is GTE 85kb - not 80kb.  The CLR will also place other smaller objects on the LOH at times.  Many byte[] often end up here regardless of size.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you have to understand the basics and pinpoint the problem in your code.

It is always a good idea to set the initial capacity, if you have a sensible estimate. If you only have an approximate guess, allocate more.

Fragmentation can only occur on the LOH (objects over 80 kB). To prevent it , try to allocate blocks of the same size.  Paradoxically, the solution might be to sometimes allocate *more* memory than you actually need.

Comment: one of (but not the only) criteria for the LOH is that the item is GTE 85kb - not 80kb. The CLR will also place other smaller objects on the LOH at times. Many byte[] often end up here regardless of size.

Comment: maybe == maybe-not

Comment: Were you stating that 'maybe' the arrays are placed there and 'maybe not'?  It is undocumented behavior so you can't (or shouldn't) rely on that since it is out of your control.  Maybe I didn't understand your comment

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that, yes pre-defining a size on collections will increase performance and memory optimization and reduce fragmentation.  See my answer here to see why - [If I set the initial size of a .NET collection and then add some items OVER this initial size, how does the collection determine the next resize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604030/if-i-set-the-initial-size-of-a-net-collection-and-then-add-some-items-over-this/45604117#45604117)

However, without analyzing a memory dump or memory profiling on the app, it's impossible to say exactly what the cause of the OOM is. Thus, impossible to conjecture if this optimization will *solve* the problem.