# If I set the initial size of a .NET collection and then add some items OVER this initial size, how does the collection determine the next resize?

Tags: .net, collections

I've started trying to set the initial size of some of my .NET collections when we know some expected max sizes. Think, pre-caching of static data etc.

If we start adding items to this collection later on the collection will resize to fit these new items in. How does it determine what the next resize will be? I thought that, if we use the default logic and don't set an initial size, it will resize based on some pre-coded logic. Now that we're set the initial size, does this screw that logic up?

is it simplistic and it's some math formula like `current size + 10%` or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the List <T> implementation, the algorithm is to start the size at 4 and then double it once the size has been reached. The best practice is to allocate a List<T> with the size at construction time. It is more efficient to allocate the size and memory upfront if you know the size. See http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Comment: So are you suggesting that the next size allocation will be double? so if i do a size of .. say 10,000 ... when I wish to add item 10,001, it will double to 20,000?

Comment: yes.
Look at how the List.Add works: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,9cc11588bffd57c1

Comment: @Pure.Krome - yes, that is why initializing the size is so important (if possible).